# Cannot copy .cpp to Project in Xcode. Also unable to delete items

Tags: c++, xcode, osx-mavericks

Late 2011 Macbook Pro with 10.9 Mavericks.

I am unable to delete the Working.1 and main.cpp files off of my "Working" project. I had an error at first asking to change the deployment target to 10.8 which I did and that seemed to have removed the error. Yet when I try to drag and copy an exercise file I've referenced to my "Working" project, nothing appears. I had to go into finder and drag it from there, but it still won't show up in Xcode. What am I doing wrong?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QrHA.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to restart your mac? It seems like this could just be a small problem with the file system.

If this does not work, reinstalling Xcode may be necessary. I also see that this is the Xcode 4 IDE, Xcode 5 is the newest IDE from Apple to build apps, have you tried to install Xcode 5?

Comment: Yes this is Xcode 4.5, let me go ahead and restart as well as update. I'm following a tutorial on Lynda.com and the guy is running Xcode 4.5 and it seems to be working for him. But let me give it a shot and get back to you.

Comment: Worked like a charm, appreciate it Jake!